# Check for substring of NSString crashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I've tried checking for an occurrence of a substring in an NSString in two ways, both have crashed. This is an NSString object I get from one of my NSManagedObject's properties.

1. Using NSRange

   `NSString *searchString = @"drive";`

   `NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];`

   if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
       NSLog(@"Found");
   }
2. Using NSScanner

   `NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:text];`

   NSLog(@"%d",[scanner scanString:searchString intoString:nil]);

Both of these work when text = @"drive" but cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes when the text is "i drive", or "drive to". Nothing happens if the text is "idrive" or "driveto".

Even stranger, sometimes the examples throw NSInvalidArgumentExceptions, saying that I tried to pass an NSCFSet or a DateComponents object to rangeOfString:, neither of which I use in my app.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is text? What does it contains?

Comment: Which method call does it crash on?  How is text created?  My bet is that text is over released and no longer valid.

Comment: @JeremyP I think what's happening is I'm getting the string attribute from my NSManagedObject, like so: text = managedObject.text; then I'm deleting managedObject. So am I right in saying that text doesn't contain a string, it contains a pointer to managedObject.text, which no longer exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you sometimes get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and sometimes get the message "*object-of-type-you-weren't expecting* does not respond to *method*" the chances are you are not retaining the object for long enough and it is getting deallocated before you get to where you use it.

If the memory hasn't been reused when you get there, things will appear to work.  If the space has been reused for another object and aligns perfectly i.e. same pointer, you'll get something like "x does not respond to selector".  If it's overwritten in such a way that the pointer does not point to a valid object, you'll get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. Thank you! I wish I could up-vote you but I have no reputation.

Comment: @ntesler:  Thanks.  Accepted answer is worth 15 rep anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The following worked perfectly for me including the spaces.

```
NSString *string = @"hello one two three";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"one two"].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"string does not contain substring");
} else {
    NSLog(@"string contains substring!");
}
```

And if you want it to be case insensitive, just convert both the string and the search string to lowercase. You should be knowing how to do that I guess.