# How to select a sub-string from an NSString using a key word?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I had written a code snippet which writes the contents of a textfield to a file. Unfortunately my code, depending on the OS, writes the file path differently

In Yosemite, The path is

```
  file:///var/folders/qg/....../myfile.txt
```

While in mountain lion the path is

```
  file://localhost/var/folders/yx....../myfile.txt
```

I have an API which takes the file path as /var/folder/xx/...../myfile.txt

I was wondering if there is a way to make a substring from /var/.. till the end of the path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for substring of NSString crashing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310040/check-for-substring-of-nsstring-crashing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along the following:

```
// Lets say pathString is an NSString of the path  
NSRange varRange = [pathString rangeOfString:@"/var/"];  
NSString *correctPath = [pathString substringFromIndex:varRange.location];
```

In the above example, you use `NSString`'s instance method `rangeOfString:` to receive the range of the wanted substring, which in this case is `/var/`, and store it into a range variable.

Then you create a new `NSString` variable, using the original `pathString`, with the use of the instance variable `substringFromIndex`, which returns a new substring, which start at the index you choose, and ends at the end of the string (which you provide the range location we've received, to identify where `/var/` begins).

Good luck mate.

Answer (score 1):

If file path is store in NSString *yourPathString, then

```
NSString *resultString= [yourPathString substringFromIndex:[yourPathString rangeOfString:@"/var"].location]];

NSLog(@"Final result : %@", resultString);
```

Try this code, hope it helps.

Comment: But The index will vary depending on the OS, no?

Comment: Yes, it will pick automatically, you will get new string which starts from "/var/ ... / tillEnd" Hope this is what you asked for?

Comment: In this way, you should not care on which machine your code is running.

Comment: I would love to but I had seen the other guy's code first. I did upvote though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67375/discussion-between-mrunal-and-morpheus).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're calling your resource, how it needs to be saved, and what that API is looking for, you'll want to use `NSURL` methods, not strings. Specifically, it sounds like you'll be most interested in using `absolutePath`, `relativePath`, `resourceIdentifier`and `pathComponents`

I would recommend reading the [URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) guide by Apple or [NSHipster's article](http://nshipster.com/nsurl/) for a more human readable answer.